# Multiple citations after float object

Tags: floats, citing

Placing one citation with footcitetext after the float is no problem. But how to o this with multiple citations? Footcitestext doesn't exist.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibtotoc,liststotoc,toc=flat,parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{farber:hybride-datenba,
Author = {Franz F{\"a}rber and Bernhard J{\"a}cksch and Christian Lemke and Philipp Gro{\ss}e and Wolfgang Lehner},
Date-Added = {2012-09-07 08:06:24 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2012-09-07 08:07:09 +0000},
Journal = {Datenbank Spektrum},
Pages = {81-92},
Title = {Hybride Datenbankarchitekturen am Beispiel der neuen SAP In-Memory-Technologie},
Volume = {10},
Year = {2010}}
@webpage{hauptfleisch:sieben-ssd-myth,
Author = {Klaus Hauptfleisch},
Date-Added = {2012-09-06 12:11:15 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2012-09-06 12:11:57 +0000},
Lastchecked = {06.09.2012},
Title = {Sieben SSD-Mythen auf dem Pr{\"u}fstand},
Url = {http://www.computerwoche.de/hardware/storage/2505349/},
Urldate = {05.06.2012},
Year = {2012},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.computerwoche.de/hardware/storage/2505349/}}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{mybib}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Header 1    &   Header 2\\
    \hline
    1   &   2\\
    2   &   3\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[GR1]{GR1\footcites[comment]{farber:hybride-datenba}[comment]{hauptfleisch:sieben-ssd-myth}}
\label{tab:gr1}
\end{table}
\footcitestext[comment]{cite1}[comment]{cite2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Now it does - expect for "footcitestext" which doesn't exist!

Comment: @PascalTurbo No, it can't be compiled because there's no `.bib` file. Use the `filecontents` package to add those data.

Comment: I thought it shall be MINIMAL... instead of writing the citation LaTeX will throw a Warning and print out the cite-key instead. This should be enough for solving the problem.

Comment: @PascalTurbo It should be a [minimal _working_ example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It's always easier for other people who are trying to solve your problem if the example compiles without adding additional code. The chance of getting valuable answers is always higher if you do this little effort.

Comment: sometimes it may be a wisdom not to insist on you opinion... Now there's a working example - minimal... don't know!

Comment: @PascalTurbo `\footcite` seems to use `\footnote`, and `\footnote` doesn't work inside a float (just gets lost, though it does change the footnote number globally).  so, even if `\footcitestext` _did_ exist, it would place footnote-like bodies at the bottom of the page, with no referencing number(s).  the [uk faq](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ftncapt) may help; it does mention a way of having footnotes at the bottom of a float.  making such things work with biblatex is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @wasteofspace yeah, minipages are a way to solve it, but doesn't fit my requirements (I can't change them). So for single Quote it works with footcitetext - sometimes the footnote is presented on the wrong page, but that's acceptable in the context of my requirements.